# How to get object of Maximum value from LiveData?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, observable, max, android-livedata

I have liveData of market data. I want one market data object which have highest 'volume'. Here, volume is string value("277927.5793846733451135"), it could be null also.

I am using below code to achieve this. but, its not working.

```
viewModel.marketlist.observe(this as LifecycleOwner, { marketdata ->
        val marketData = marketdata.getOrNull()
        if(marketData !=null) {
           val mData: MarketData? = marketData.marketData?.maxByOrNull { checkNotNull(it.volume) }

            if (mData != null) {
                binding.textViewPrice.text = mData.price
            }
        }
        else {
            //TODO
        }
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
viewModel.marketList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { marketData ->
    val maxData = marketData.getOrNull()?.marketData?.let { dataValues ->
        dataValues.maxByOrNull { it.volume?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: -1.0 }
    }
    
    if (maxData != null) {
        binding.textViewPrice.text = maxData.price
    }
}
```

I cleaned up the `observe` call a bit, then I'm checking if `marketData.getOrNull().marketData` is null right away with my `let { ... }` block.

If you do have `marketData` (the inner one), it'll then safely call `maxByOrNull { it.volume }`.

Comment: I have tried your code which is not crashing but its not giving the highest volume data. volume could be null as well it could be 277927.5793846733451135 this.

Comment: Using it.volume.toString().toFloatOrNull(), not working.

Comment: @BhoomikaBrahmbhatt - do you have some test data you can share? It could also be an issue that you're comparing `String` values rather than `Double` values.

Comment: I have created chat room named Kotlin . can you please join?

Comment: I will share API code response.

Comment: @BhoomikaBrahmbhatt - can you allow me talk access in the chat room?